# How do you get a dog to come while it's standing up in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you get a dog to come in minecraft while it's standing up?

Comment: I assume you already tamed it?

Answer (score 2):

### Obtaining a bone

I assume you mean to come to you, or to follow you. If so, you're looking for a bone. These are dropped by the skeleton, the spider jockey, and the wither skeleton. Therefore, you mustn't be in peaceful mode, and they'll only spawn when it's dark.

[image]

### Taming the wolf

Once you've obtained the bone, hold it in you hand, stand near the wolf and it'll follow you - it'll also follow you if you punch it, but this isn't advised. To claim the wolf as yours, right click it with some bones in your hand until some hearts appear and a collar appears around it's neck.

### Standing up and following you

You can then right click the dog again to toggle between sitting and standing, once standing the dog will follow you every where and even will teleport if it's stuck. It won't however go into the nether, I guess it's just too scared.

### Sitting down and dyeing the collar

If the dog is sitting, it won't follow you and instead will just sit where you tell it to - much better behaved than my dog! You can also change the collar colour by right clicking with dye equipped.